# Function to draw a line between two specified points for OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been trying to figure out a way to create a function which draws a line between two points in OpenGL 3.3. I don't want to use `GL_LINES` as that is too ugly. I am using [this library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199525/Drawing-nearly-perfect-2D-line-segments-in-OpenGL) but it is written for basic OpenGL, and is incompatible with 3.3, so I had to modify it a little.

Currently, the line method works as provided in the library, with a slight modification in the end. After the method calculates all it needs for a nice line (the coordinates of the vertices and the colors), instead of placing vertices on screen with the glBegin stuff, it now stores them in an array. Then, I pass this array as buffer data to a VBO, and finally, I draw the vertices using glDrawArrays.

To make this work, I have pointed out that the VBO is GL_DYNAIC_DRAW, and have preallocated the memory required for the array.

In the line method I use this:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
```

After this, I specify the vertex attributes and I draw the line.

This works perfectly fine, but the problem is that it's significantly slower than the basic OpenGL version that the library uses. To test this, I created 2 programs (1 for basic and one for core OpenGL) which draw 10,000 lines in one render loop.

I believe this is due to the constant changing of the buffer data with glBufferSubData. My question is how can I make this faster (or at least as fast as the basic OpenGL)? Just to specify, I need this as a generalized method like in the library, so specifying in the beginning how many lines and where they will be for the duration of the program will not be possible.

Comment: The idea of buffering anything (not only in OpenGL) is to accumulate some small parts in a single array of data and then dump (bind/whatever) it all with a single pass. So what you need is to accumulate each "draw a line" request in a buffer (say as a workaround you can use `std::vector` which has dynamic size, but for future you'll need to come up with a smarter accumulation), then when the drawing moment finally comes you bind this buffer just once and clear it (or not clear, depending on your intentions)

Comment: "*I don't want to use GL_LINES as that is too ugly.*" Then what are you using to draw lines? Triangles?

Comment: I am using a triangle strip.

Comment: Alex Larionov, so as far as I understand, instead of constantly updating the data in the small buffer and drawing it, I should instead just store it, and when I reach the end of the render loop, send it all to a buffer and draw it in a single call, is that correct?

Comment: @NikolayGanev pretty much yes, but don't limit yourself with just a single buffer, it might be several buffers, just not too many, not "a single buffer for a single line"

Comment: @AlexLarionov Thanks a lot! I did what you said, and it's now 2x faster when it's not constantly changing the data in the buffer.

Comment: I would expect it be faster than x2, so maybe there is still room for improvements

Comment: I guess there's always room for improvements. I also have to say that it _looks_ as if it is 2x faster. That's only based on the test I have, which is also on a remote pc, so there are multiple things to interfere. It will likely be much faster if I do it on my native PC. Regardless, it is good enough for me. Thanks again.